# How to change url protocol in lightning-datatable field with type='url'

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I have a `lightning-datatable` with many fields, some of them having `type="url"`. When I create the `url` attribute for these fields, like this:

```js
element.url = element.active ? `${window.location.origin}/${rowElem.id}` : `##`;
```

I am getting an `href` like this:

[image]

How I can remove `https://` protocol, to get

```js
href="##"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like `lightning-datatable` (actually `lightning-formatted-url`, which it uses) directly supports other protocols besides `http` or `https`.  This is probably to prevent Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) vulnerabilities.  Even the `mailto` protocol appears to be unsupported.

You can specify a relative URL using `/`, `./`, etc. See [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-url/documentation) for `lightning-formatted-url`.

To fulfill your requirement, you may need to [create a custom data type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_table_custom_types) for `lightning-datatable`.